# TeeChart: axis and series spacing

Tags: c++builder, teechart

Using C++Builder 10.2 (Tokyo), I'm creating an Area chart via TeeChart. Creating the chart however, is not the problem. The problems I'm trying to solve is

1. I cannot seem to find a way to stop the bottom axis from incrementing. By this, I mean that I have EXACT dates that I want to plot, not a range of dates. For example, point 1 might be 04/01/2017 and point 2 might be 06/01/2017, but the TeeChart automatically creates a point for 05/01/2017 - which I don't want. Also, it doesn't place a label for 06/01/2017.
2. Is there a way to add empty space between the area series?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I cannot seem to find a way to stop the bottom axis from incrementing.
>   By this, I mean that I have EXACT dates that I want to plot, not a
>   range of dates. For example, point 1 might be 04/01/2017 and point 2
>   might be 06/01/2017, but the TeeChart automatically creates a point
>   for 05/01/2017 - which I don't want. Also, it doesn't place a label
>   for 06/01/2017.

You can try setting the bottom axis `LabelStyle` to `talPointValue`:

```
  Chart1->Axes->Bottom->LabelStyle = talPointValue;
```

> Is there a way to add empty space between the area series?

You can add a dummy (empty) `TAreaSeries` between two series to create that separation in the Depth axis. Ie, in Delphi:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var i, j, n: Integer;
    tmpSeries: TChartSeries;
begin
  for i:=0 to 4 do
    with Chart1.AddSeries(TAreaSeries) do
    begin
      Title:='Series' + IntToStr(i+1);
      FillSampleValues;
    end;

  n:=Chart1.SeriesCount-1;
  j:=1;
  for i:=0 to n-1 do
  begin
    tmpSeries:=Chart1.AddSeries(TAreaSeries);
    tmpSeries.ShowInLegend:=False;

    while Chart1.SeriesList.IndexOf(tmpSeries) > j do
      Chart1.SeriesUp(tmpSeries);

    Inc(j, 2);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: I had already done the blank series trick (thank you anyway) but I did not know about the _labelStyle_ option. Thanks!!